# ruby on rails - error accessing to public directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to ask you if is possible to show data, which I've to
saved in /public/my_dir_for_data.

If I try to display an image from this directory, I get "Routing error".
Probably when I would to saved the data to root of my application, e.g.
/my_data, everything will be ok... but I like this structure of RoR
application and I will be glad, if I could to use the directory in in
/public...

Exist any way, how to do? (and simultaneously security?)

Comment: What code are you using to try and display an image?

Comment: Nope, I am not using any code, I am writing http://www.domain.com/my_dir_for_data/example.png in my browser. I guess rails thinks "my_dir_for_data" is a controller.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a file exists, rails won't go into the controller stack, if it can't find the file, it will assume that it's a dynamic action and go into the controller stack.

So, if a file exists at `#{Rails.root}/public/directory/file.png` and you navigate to `domain.com/directory/file.png` it should work render the file.

Are you sure all the directory and file names are the same on both sides?

Answer (score 1):

The above problem is due to the configuration settings in config/environment/production.rb file.
If you add the below line, the issue will be solved.
config.serve_static_assets = true

But this line is deprecated since rails 4 and it will be removed in rails 5.0. For this, the new configuration parameter as below is introduced. You will get a warning as below, but the static files will be served.

DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly.

So, better if you use the config.serve_static_assets parameters to true, that will also serve the purpose.